# Way to tell if WCF service is called via HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: wcf

Let's say you've got a WCF service that is accessible via HTTP and HTTPS, but you want only certain methods to be available with HTTPS-- how can I check if the current request is HTTPS? Since HttpContext is empty, you can't simply check HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection -- any other ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider that WCF applications can also be hosted as a Windows service, with no ASP.NET at all, in which case there is no such thing as "secure" vs. "insecure."  That is one reason why WCF does not attempt to make this information available.

One option would be to run the WCF service in [ASP.NET Compatibility Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx), where you *do* have access to the `HttpContext.Current` instance.

My choice, however, would simply be to create a different, SSL-only service for the secure operations.  I really think you'd want to do this anyway, so the contract is explicit; otherwise you're left doing runtime checks and clients may have no idea that the methods they're trying to use aren't allowed.

"Best practice" in a web service is to make these types of restrictions as explicit as possible, and having a separate service available only over SSL is *by far* the clearest means of describing your service's restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

( Building on comment from @Aaronaught within answer by Matt Ellen... )

It looks like

```
OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To.Scheme
```

contains "http" or "https" among others ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is served over a different port to HTTP. Assuming you know the ports, perhaps checking that would suffice.

Comment: Right, so how do you find the port that's in use?  Meta-problem.

Comment: @Aaronaught: `OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To` should return the uri that the request is sent to.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var iwrc = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
var isHttps = iwrc.UriTemplateMatch.BaseUri.Scheme.Equals("https", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

This is very easy, does not rely on port numbers and works just fine in a self-host WCF server (with no IIS in <s>site</s> sight).